# Longitudinal design: Which method to use if the dependent variable was measured during fewer occasions than the predictors?

Tags: time-series, panel-data, growth-model, age

I have a longitudinal dataset with 8 repeated measurement occasion and approximately 100 cases. Some of the explanatory variables are time-variant, other stay the same over time. Some might be categorical, others continuous. The dependent variable is continuous.
Now the problematic part: Due to the nature of the study the dependent variable can only be measured during the last two measurement occasions. How could I examine the influence of the different predictors on the independent variable?
While I first thought to utilize hierarchical growth curve modelling, I believe that this approach will have problems due to the fact that the dependent variable cannot be measured at most time points. Correct?
(Note:  “age in month” is measured during each occasion. Although participants are expected to have approximately the same age during each measurement occasions, the data would of cause show a variation of a few month. Consequently “age in month” would serve as the variable that represents time and delivers far more than 8 occasions, right?). Which statistical approach is feasible to handle this data?

Kind regards, Rasul

Comment: Can you clarify your scientific question for us? At the moment it seems to me that you may not have the data you need to answer your apparent question.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to examine the influence of (developing, thus time-variant) pre-academic skills (e.g. measures of different cognitive capacities) on later academic variables such as academic achievement. As the study focuses on pre-school students (3-4 years old at the beginning) academic achievement can only be measured after the transition to primary schools takes place and students receive their first grades.
All the pre-school variables however can be measured during the whole duration of the study.